# Sqlite exception while trying to add parsed values of json to a sqlite table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Im using the following query to create a table with name shippingMaster.

`private static final String CREATE_SHIPMENTMASTER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SHIPMENTMASTER + "("+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_STATUS + " TEXT" + ")";`

within onCreate method, I'm executing the above query.

To add values to the database, Im using the following method,

```
public void addShipmentMaster (ShipmentMasterDao shipmentMasterDao){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_ID, shipmentMasterDao.getId());
    values.put(KEY_STATUS,shipmentMasterDao.getStatus());

    db.insert(TABLE_SHIPMENTMASTER, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

**UPDATED CODE:**
I'm parsing  a json adding those values to db as follows,

```
JSONObject value = new JSONObject(notificationResponse.getString("value"));
                            JSONObject shipmentMaster = value.getJSONObject("shipment_master");
                            Iterator<String> shipmentMasterIterator = shipmentMaster.keys();
                            String status = null;
                            String key = null;
                            final int numberLenth = shipmentMaster.length();

                            while (shipmentMasterIterator.hasNext()) {
                            key = shipmentMasterIterator.next();
                            status = shipmentMaster.optString(key);


                           db.addShipmentMaster(new ShipmentMasterDao(Integer.valueOf(key), status));
                            }
```

Json that im parsing is as follows,

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "value": {
    "shipment_master": {
      "1": "Order Placed",
      "2": "In Production",
      "3": "Quality Check In progress",
      "4": "Goods received for shipment",
      "5": "Stuffing in progress",
      "6": "Cargo Shipped"
    }
  }
}
```

It throws an error message as follows,

`E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: shipmentMaster
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting status=Cargo Shipped id=0                                                       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: shipmentMaster (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO shipmentMaster(status,id) VALUES (?,?)`

Comment: Unfortunately your table is no created. SO please cross check your `SQL CREATE Table command` and do as @Jas said

Comment: Table is not created and check database version also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log clearly says the issue. `no such table: shipmentMaster`. Check your command for creating table and if that is fine, try uninstalling the app from your device and install again.

Replace your create statement with this:

```
   private static final String CREATE_SHIPMENTMASTER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SHIPMENTMASTER
                            + "("
                            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                            + KEY_STATUS + " TEXT" );";
```

Comment: thank you! it says something like ` android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)`

Comment: You are not supposed to add same key id in multiple colums

Comment: i will post how i do this...i guess the problem is with the loop

Comment: i have updated it. Im not sure what could be the error

Comment: check your key id values and tell me whether there are any duplicate values